# Накопительные итоги

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос

Есть таблица `company`. В ней хранятся следующие данные: ид, название компании, бюджет, ид на родительскую компанию (parent ид), общая сумма. Надо посчитать бюджет компании + бюджет дочерних компаний. Я это делаю в столбце общая сумма(total).

```
"SELECT o.id, o.title, o.budget, o.pid, 
(select sum(o1.budget)+o.budget from company o1 where o1.pid=o.id) total
FROM company o ORDER BY o.id";
```

По данному запросу выводятся суммы только на уровень ниже, а мне нужно вычислить бюджеты всех подчиненных дочерних компаний.

Comment: Неудачно вы СУБД выбрали, вам нужны рекурсивные запросы, которые  есть практически во всех современных СУБД, кроме MySQL. У вас путь только в сторону хранимой процедуры и возможно временных таблиц.

Answer (score 1):

С вашей нынешней структурой (`Adjacency List`) чтобы просуммировать данные придется сделать несколько запросов.

Если не переключаться на другую СУБД, вы можете выбрать другой способ представления древовидных данных: `Nested Sets`, `Materialized Path` или `Closure Table`.

См. обзор http://www.slideshare.net/quipo/trees-in-the-database-advanced-data-structures/